# appending an array of string to arraylist of type Integer in Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList<Integer>` called `nodes`. I want to assign elements from array[] to elements in ArrayList. Such that 1st element in arraylist will have first element in array as its property.. and so on. However, there are only 6 elements in array and thus for 7th element its again first element from array[]. Array is of type Integer.

```
public static String[] Interest = new String[] {"I1","I2","I3","I4","I5","I6"};

public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Enter number of nodes");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int n = sc.nextInt();
    for(int i=0;i<=n;i++) {
        nodes.add(i);
    }

    System.out.println(nodes);
}
```

I want to set up an interest profile for each element in `node`. For that I have an array called `Interest` which has 6 elements in it. Now say for the first element in `node`, I want to set up preferences for Interests. For example, the first element could have interest profile as I1 = 10, I2 = 8, ..., I6 = 2 and so on.

I am thinking of using a method like `SetIntensity(ArrayList element, array of integers)` which will set interest profile for an element passed as a parameter. I am not sure if it's correct but I am expecting something like this:

```
public static void setInterest(List<String> array){

    String[] Interest = new String[]{"I1","I2","I3","I4","I5","I6"};

    for(int k=0;k<array.size();k++){
        array.get(k);
        for(int j=0;j<Interest.length;j++){

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code where your method of converting the array to a list is not working for you?

Comment: Please provide the declaration of "nodes". Also, please clarify what is expected and what is actually happening.

Comment: So you have a list of nodes, and each node has a value for I1, a value for I2, a value for I3, I4, I5, I6.  Right?

Comment: What do you mean by `1st element has interest profile as I1 = 10, I2 = 8...I6 = 2`

Comment: Yes @FiveNine thats correct..

Comment: @Zhenxiao Hao.. FiveNine mentioned it correctly.

Comment: I see my question has been put on hold. But FiveNine has already answered it. Due to lack of time, I was not able to accept the answer which I have done now. And also, I see there have been many edits which I have accepted as they clear the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need a `Node` class with a `Map` to store preferences.

```
class Node {

    Integer id;
    Map<String, Integer> interestPreferences;

    public Node(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.interestPreferences = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    }

    void setPreference(String key, Integer value) {
        interestPreferences.put(key, value);
    }

    Interest getPreference(String key) {
        return interestPreferences.get(key);
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
public static List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
public static String[] Interest = new String[] {"I1","I2","I3","I4","I5","I6"};

public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Enter number of nodes");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int n = sc.nextInt();
    for(int i=0;i<=n;i++) {
        Node node = new Node(i);
        node.setPreference("I1", 10);
        node.setPreference("I2", 8);
        //....
        node.setPreference("I6", 2);
        nodes.add(node);
    }

    System.out.println(nodes);
}
```

Comment: There is more to this code than I have posted in question. I just wish my other methods also work out when I create a List of type <Node>. Thank you for answer.